# Prove there exists a bijective function $\left\{a,\cdots,b\right\}\rightarrow\left\{a+k,\cdots,b+k\right\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I must prove that there exists a bijective function $\left\{a,\cdots,b\right\}\rightarrow\left\{a+k,\cdots,b+k\right\}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ (this is not homework). This is the proof I've come up with so far:

> *proof* Let $A$ and $B$ be sets such that $B:=\left\{a\in A:a+k,\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$. Now let  $f:A\rightarrow
>  B$ be a function and $x,y\in A$ such that
>    $f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$. But every element in $A$ has one
>    and only one corresponding element in $B$, thus $x=y$. Hence $f$ is
>    injective.  Because $\left|A\right|=\left|B\right|$ and $f$ is
>    injective, $f$ is also surjective. Therefore, $f$ is
>    bijective.$\;\square$

Does my reasoning make sense, or are there improvements that may be made? The step I'm unsure about is my deduction that $f$ is injective. The two sets are obviously of the same cardinality, but I can't think of any other way to show that $f$ is injective.

Comment: Your definition of B is wrong. It should be something like $B=\{b \in \Bbb N: b=a+k, a\in A, k \in \Bbb N\}.

Comment: Also, you're using what you're trying to prove in your proof: "every element in A has one and only one corresponding element in B"... That's the definition of a bijection.

Comment: Your reasoning it is not right, your set $B$ is wrongly written and your function $f$ is not properly defined. **HINT** Better write $B=\{ a+k : a \in A\}$ for $k\in \mathbb N$. Then let $f:A\to B$, be given by $f(a)=a+k$, now prove that $f$ is indeed a biyection !

Comment: It looks as if you're proving that every function $f : A \to B$ is bijective, which is clearly not true. However, you can construct a function that is bijective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two sets $A$ and $B$ the only thing you need for the *existence* of a bijection is that $|A| = |B|$.

In fact, we say that sets $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality if there is a bijection between them.

Comment: and if $|A|\ne|B|$ no bijection exists.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yup - the existence of a bijection is the definition of same cardinality!

Comment: I see. Then for either equal or unequal cardinalities we can (always) have a surjective function, but not necessarily an injective one, which would require the sets to be of equal size for there to exist a bijection.

Comment: @jm324354 Well, if you define a function $f$ from $A$ to $B$, that doesn't necessarily mean that every value of $A$ and $B$ have to be used by the function. It is true that you can always have an injective function, but not necessarily a surjective one.

Comment: if $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary sets, then we say that $|A| = |B|$ holds if there exists a bijection between them ([this is the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality#Comparing_sets)). Therefore it seems that your argument is circular reasoning.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn How is this circular? I'm using the fact that the sets clearly have the same cardinality to assert that there is a bijection between the two.

Comment: As you said, by definition two sets have the same cardinality if and only if there exists a bijection between them. Thus, proving that there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$ is equivalent to proving that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality. Both of these statements are clearly true, but you have to actually prove it (by exhibiting a bijection). Of course, further along your way towards becoming a mathematician you can start taking these results for granted, as you proved them before (if $A$ and $B$ are finite and have the same number of elements, then there is a bijection between the two).

Comment: My point is: I get the idea that the OP has not yet proven this more general fact: if $A$ and $B$ are finite and have the same number of elements, then there is a bijection between them.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn So you're saying that I'm using machinery (relatively simple machinery, at that) when you suspect OP hasn't learned such machinery yet. That doesn't make my answer invalid, nor does it make it *circular*. This site isn't a site where you get one answer per question. You get many answers and you learn something from each one (hopefully). From my answer, OP can learn something he or she didn't know before. There certainly is value in that.

Comment: Well, your answer is still circular reasoning, unless you mean by $|A| = |B|$ something other than the usual definition (that there is a bijection between $A$ and $B$). For instance, if you mean _$A$ and $B$ are finite and have the same number of elements_, then I suppose it does answer the question.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn Well, yes, that is exactly what I mean. One can easily see that $A$ and $B$, as two finite sets, have the same cardinality (number of elements). I'm sorry if that was unclear to you for any reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25677/discussion-between-josse-van-dobben-de-bruyn-and-soke).

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x+k$ is automatically surjective. If $f(x)=f(y)$, i.e. $x+k=y+k$, then $x=y$ which implies it is injective.

Comment: i had changed it.